# Should i omit logically implied guard clauses in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Given a function that is guaranteed to get a number as an input, should i include logically implied guard clauses, or should i omit them?

```
def check(x) when x < 5, do: :ok
def check(x) when x >= 5, do: :error

#or

def check(x) when x < 5, do: :ok
def check(x), do: :error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second guard is redundant, despite whether the input is guaranteed or not, it will induce even less recognizable error message on non-integer input. Instead of:

```
def check(x) when x >= 5, do: :error
```

one might do more precise check:

```
def check(x) when not is_integer(x) and not is_float(x), do: :type_error
def check(x) when x < 5, do: :ok
def check(x), do: :value_error # here x is guaranteed to be numeric ge 5
```

Comment: I think a no clause matches error on invalid input (OP's first code) would be better if the OP is sure he'll never call it on invalid inputs. Also, `is_number(x) == is_integer(x) or is_float(x)`.

Comment: @Dogbert Maybe and likely, I just shed a light on how to cover everything. Yes, I am aware of `is_number`, I just wanted to be as precise as possible.